# CCleaner as cleanup tool

Tags: powershell

I want to use Powershell to run ccleaner automatically during logoff which i will add as logoff script.

I want ccleaner to run regardless which folder it is.

if not ProgramFiles(x86) then ProgramFiles.

```
$I="$env:ProgramFiles(x86)\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe"
$y="$env:ProgramFiles\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe"
if ((test-path $I) -or (test-path $y))
**{& $y '/AUTO' -or $I '/AUTO'}**
else
{ will add temp cleaning script here}
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: The general consensus is Don't use CCleaner. Not related, not an answer but not worth the risk. https://superuser.com/questions/199151/should-i-use-registry-cleaners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this

```
$path32 = Join-Path "$env:ProgramFiles(x86)" "Ccleaner"
$path64 = Join-Path $env:ProgramFiles "Ccleaner"

if(Test-Path $path32) {
    $exePath = Join-Path $path32 "Ccleaner.exe"
    & $exePath "/auto"
} elseif (Test-Path $path64) {
    $exePath = Join-Path $path64 "Ccleaner.exe"
    & $exePath "/auto"
} else {
    #manual temp cleaning
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
$path32 = Join-Path ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} "Ccleaner"
$path64 = Join-Path $env:ProgramFiles "Ccleaner"

if(Test-Path $path32) {
    $exePath = Join-Path $path32 "Ccleaner.exe"
    & $exePath "/auto"
} elseif (Test-Path $path64) {
    $exePath = Join-Path $path64 "Ccleaner.exe"
    & $exePath "/auto"
} else {
    #manual temp cleaning
}
```

Comment: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'.
At line:3 char:13
+ if(Test-Path <<<<  = True) {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

Comment: My code is working (at least on my system) and does not include the word "True". Please try running it with no prior modification ;-).

Comment: i so glad u guys helped me its useful to keep cleaning the servers i wll add as logoff script